# Find div with attr and change its style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to find a div that has an attribute data-date, and if it is equal to todays date, change its style.

This is how I form that element (I have to do it in JS):

```
for (let i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
      const someDate = new Date(datesArray[i]);
      const date = document.createElement('div');
      date.setAttribute('id', '' + new Date(datesArray[i]).getTime());
      date.setAttribute('class', 'date');
      date.setAttribute('data-date', new Date(datesArray[i]).toDateString());
      date.innerText = '' + formatDate(someDate);

      daysRowFragment.appendChild(

      const formattedDate = date.innerText;
      const className = formattedDate.substring(0, formattedDate.indexOf(' ')).toLowerCase() === 'sat' ||
        formattedDate.substring(0, formattedDate.indexOf(' ')).toLowerCase() === 'sun' ? 'day weekend' : 'day';

      $(".calendar-row").append(`
            <div id="` + new Date(datesArray[i]).getDate() + '-' + i + `" data-date="` + new Date(datesArray[i]).toDateString() + `" class="` + className + `">
            </div>
        `);
    }
 daysRow.appendChild(daysRowFragment);
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work (date formats are not the same):

```
$('.date').each(function (index, dateCell) {

      console.log($(dateCell).attr('data-date'));
      console.log(new Date());
      if ($(dateCell).attr('data-date') == new Date()) {
        $(dateCell).css('background-color', 'red');
      }
    });
```

Comment: can you provide the outputted html please?

Comment: @MarcelWasilewski ugh, its a calendar, shows 30 days, I think i would just need to format the date

Comment: Could the difference be that you're using `new Date(datesArray[i]).toDateString()` to create the attribute and just `new Date()` when comparing it? Furthermore, what is the output of `console.log($(dateCell).attr('data-date'));`, could you show us?

Comment: Then maybe show at least how the date in the data-date attribute is formatted

Answer (score 0):

Ah I messed up, just had to put:

```
if ($(dateCell).attr('data-date') == new Date().toDateString()) {
        $(dateCell).css('background-color', 'red');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I try to make a solution for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "[data-date='todaydate']" ).each(function(){
                $(this).css('color','red');
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <span id="term1" data-date='todaydate'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 1</span>
    <span id="term2" data-date='nottoday'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2</span>
    <span id="term3" data-date='nottoday'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 3</span>
    <span id="term4" data-date='nottoday'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 4</span>
    <span id="term5" data-date='todaydate'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 5</span>
    <span id="term6" data-date='nottoday'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 6</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Output: [image]
Now you can also do it.